# How to Solve ImportError in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm new to django and I'm facing some difficulties in creating a user from the AbstractUser model. Now I'm starting wondering if my user model is not being build in the right way. This is my Owner model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CASCADE, BooleanField
from user_app.forms import LoginForm
        
        
class user_type(AbstractUser):
    is_user = models.BooleanField('Is user', default=False)
    is_police = models.BooleanField('Is police', default=False)
    is_insurance = models.BooleanField('Is insurance', default=False)
    is_rto: BooleanField = models.BooleanField('Is rto', default=False)
    
class Owner(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    login_id = models.ForeignKey(LoginForm, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    aadhar_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    photo = models.FileField()
    mobile = models.IntegerField()
    licence = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

and there another import error occurred in forms.py. this is my form.py

```
from django import forms
from user_app.models import user_type
    
    
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    "class": "form-control"
                }
            )
        )
    password = forms.CharField(
            widget = forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs = {
                    "class": "form-control"
                }
            )
        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = user_type
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_user','is_insurance', 'is_police', 'is_rto')
```

and when I'm running this project using 'python manage.py runserver' then it shows

```
 File "D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from user_app.forms import LoginForm
  File "D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\forms.py", line 2, in <module>
    from user_app.models import user_type
ImportError: cannot import name 'user_type' from 'user_app.models' (D:\PROJECT\Digital-Vehicle-Project\digi_vehicle\user_app\models.py)
```

Comment: removing from user_app.models import user_type  causes this error  (name error) model = UserType
NameError: name 'UserType' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Owner model, in this line:

```
login_id = models.ForeignKey(LoginForm, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

The foreign key needs to be attributed to a model only. But in your code, there is a ForeignKey associated with a form. So, code a model here. After this no need to import this:

```
from user_app.forms import LoginForm
```

Hence, it will avoid the circular import error you are facing.